# Android Swipe Finger

Tags: android

Please look at this picture

[image: gesture]

Basically you swipe your finger down in that area and it shows more.. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ViewFlipper` or (horizontal)`ListView` , each page/item of the `ViewFlipper`/`ListView` will contain one of these view (I bet they are images). For swiping you can  ``` implement``onTouchListener ``` or `GestureDetector`. Override `onFling()` method, and measure the distance between the initial X-coordinate when the user touches the screen and the final x-coordinate when the user releases the touch screen with method `event1.getX()` and `event2.getX()`. `Do not measure` the motion on the `y-axis` since --->(to right, you have motion only on the `x-axis`). Intialize some `MINIMUM_DISTANCE`  to compare with the result from difference between the first touch and release touch coordinate (`event1.getX() - event2.getX()`).

Comment: How do you mean whole screen? Does this applies on the whole screen? Yes. But you an measure if it is in the area where you want.

Comment: I mean measure and test if the event occured in the area you want. Let say If(event1.getX() > areaofthethumbnail )

Comment: the comment was aimed towards the OP. If the OP just needs a widget, there's no need to reprogram existing functionality.